Necessity of Singularity in General Relativity
The Schwarzschild solution is the standard example used to describe a black hole, its important points being the event horizon and the central singularity. But this solution is derived by assuming an empty spacetime around a point with a "mass" parameter.
All geodesics inside the horizon point inexorably inward for this solution. But why does this preclude a clump of matter or "collapsar" at the center? For example, the Schwarzschild solution also describes the field around a planet, except that the planetary matter occupies the field's central region. At the surface of the planet, the field description transitions from the exterior to the interior Schwarzschild solution (assuming idealized geometry, obviously).
What is it that preludes the predicted field, even at $r<r_{Schwarzschild}$, from simply terminating at the surface of a collapsar of dense matter, and taking some other form inside it?
(Obviously the field could be solved numerically for such a structure, rather than fitting it to a theoretical metric like Schwarzschild, but I presume something happens in the equations that makes this unphysical.)

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18981/ Also I just noticed this question, duplicate?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Well the famous singularity theorems show (very very roughly speaking) that in the theory of classical GR, collapse beyond horizon implies a singularity. Classical GR is not the true theory of physics, and quantum gravity effects might do something like what you say. But probably not for $r$ outside the region of Planck scale curvature, which is effectively almost a singularity anyway. Also, too dense "planets" require infinite pressure. Look up singularity theorems and Buchdahl limit. There are metrics like the one you want e.g. Bardeen, Hayward. Whether they exist in physics is another question.


What is it that preludes the predicted field, even at $r<r_{Schwarzschild}$, from simply terminating at the surface of a collapsar of dense matter, and taking some other form inside it?

This is rather simple. The radial direction inside the horizon is timelike. Nothing can stay at a constant radius inside for exactly the same reason why we cannot stay in time at noon without moving to afternoon. No matter what structure you can imagine, a collapsar or whatever, inside the horizon it must move forward in time toward the region known as singularity where time ends.
The shape of this region is a moment of time along an infinitely long spacelike Euclidean line in the coordinate chart - this region is not a part of the spacetime manifold. In other words, the singularity is a coordinate location that does not exist in the real spacetime. See a visual diagram and geodesics here for details: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2929400
Please note that commonly the term collapsar refers to a collapsed star whose matter remains outside the horizon in the coordinates of a remote observer. Since the radial direction outside is spacelike, matter can appear to remain at approximately the same radius indefinitely.

I think your answer is assuming that the Schwarzschild metric (or a similar one) continues all the way to $r=0$.  My question is, what if the spacetime follows Schwarzschild up to the surface of some body, and then inside it changes to something else? I.e. just like it does for the spacetime around a planet, except the surface of the planet would happen to be at $r<r_S$

@RC_23 You are correct. This statement in your question, “ a clump of matter or "collapsar" at the center*”, sounded like you mean “somewhat deep inside the horizon”.  Hence my answer. However, if you mean the presence of some spacetime other than the extended Schwarzschild starting exactly from the horizon, then nothing precludes this possibility. The most known solution of this type is by Oppenheimer-Snyder, although it does not refer to a solid body. There is another recent paper that does claim a solid body inside the horizon. I will look for the link.

That's interesting. Yes, my question could be simply stated: Could a planet or star, however exotic, exist with a radius of say $r_S/2$, and if not, why?  If you were to examine the local metric as a function of radius $g(r)$, in this scenario it would be Schwarzschild until very close to the surface of the object, and then at lower radii, something else.

@RC_23 Here is one “no singularity” link: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1007810414531 - “this categorically shows that GTR is not only ‘the most beautiful physical theory,’ but also, is the only, naturally, singularity free theory”.

@RC_23 “Could a planet or star, however exotic, exist with a radius of say rS/2,” - As mentioned above, this is hypothetically possible only if the spacetime inside $r_s$ is not Schwarzschild. Otherwise the inner radius is timelike, so your $r_s/2$ refers to a moment of time of the collapse, but not to a location in space. So if your surface is “below” (or rather “after”) the horizon, then it would be hard to justify stitching the Schwarzschild spacetime outside with a non-Schwarzschild spacetime just inside the horizon in vacuum with no material substance to explain the change.

@RC_23 Another example is a collapsar inside a hollow spherical shell of, say, the same mass. This way the shell stays at just above $r_s$ for the total mass while the collapsar stays at a lower radius. The shell at the horizon allows for the type of spacetime change there and prevents the radius from becoming timelike inside.

According to Thorne and Susskind, the fact that a black hole's mass is distributed as a 2-dimensional surface (the event horizon), and not a volume, indicates that the black hole has no interior.
You can also look at it as a singularity smeared out across space (but not time).
You want to impose a euclidian geometry on space that really isn't euclidian because of its metric signature.
The fact that spacetime is non-euclidean only becomes noticeable at unusual extreme instances, but a BH is one of those instances. Another is the time dilation experienced by GPS satellites. And the precession of Mercury's perihelion.
A black hole is a topological hole in the manifold. Spacetime bends around it. There is no "there" there.
You just have to accept reality the way it is, and stop trying to figure out what's "inside" the black hole.
If that seems somehow unsatisfying and even irritating, take it up with God. I just work here (as his humble PR explainer).

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
