Why are black holes referred to as infinite when their mass is not infinite and there is nothing infinite in the current universe?
Are they not actually just "really, really deep"? It seems like all the descriptions of them being infinite are actually people actually just saying they are "nearly infinite," or seemingly using the term "infinite" unscientifically because it's so deep it "might as well be infinite," but in reality it's not?

What are you reading or listening to that says black holes are infinite?

I could see "infinite" meaning "falling all the way in takes an infinite amount of time", which is true if you're measuring naively with coordinate time instead of affine parameters like $\tau$.

Perhaps you are referring to how spacetime curvature invariants become arbitrarily large as one approaches the singularity. This is a prediction of General Relativity’s classical model of a black hole. It is possible — and perhaps likely — that quantum effects in a better theory leave the curvature finite. But how could we ever know for sure “in reality”?

there is nothing infinite in the current universe Why are you so sure of that? Have you been everywhere and checked?

Misspoke a bit. Meant "infinite density" & "infinite gravitational curvature." Google: "The defining characteristic of a singularity is its infinite density, meaning an infinitely large amount of mass is crammed into an infinitely small space." Is it not actually just a really, really large amount of mass in a really, really small space? Since the math/physics not translatable to layperson, broader question is just re: accuracy of word use "infinite" in physics. If universe weighs 10^53 kg, is ~13.8 billion years old, and 93 billion light years across, how can there be anything infinite in it?

What does the mass, age, and size of the observable universe have to do with the densities of things within it? Electrons are modeled as point particles with infinite mass density and charge density, but they still have finite mass and charge.

Is it not actually just… How would we know? We can’t go into a black hole, look around, and come back out. All we have is models. The model we use says the curvature is infinite. You’re free to not like it and invent a better model. (I think string theorists already have.)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18981/2451 and links therein.

Is it not actually just a really, really large amount of mass in a really, really small space?
No, the current model of a black hole is a finite mass $M$ occupying a zero volume point, so if we naïvely compute the density, we get
$$ \rho = \frac{M}{0} \sim \infty. $$ So it is "truly" an infinity in the model.  But, no one really believes this model is accurate near the singularity, and in actuality, it might very well be a very large mass in a small but finite space, as you say. But we need a quantum theory of gravity to model such a thing

@RC_23 Your comment above is incorrect. A singularity is not a part of the metric space and therefore has no concepts of mass, volume, or density. Furthermore, the Schwarzschild singularity is not an object in space, but a moment of time in the infinite future. What is the “density” or “mass” or “volume” of the moment of midnight tomorrow as you observe from today? It is just absurd. Finallly energy and time are Fourier conjugates - when time ends energy disappears. So even if the singularity were a “place”, it would still have a zero mass.

@ImaginaryUnit While a good answer would be quite technical involving the evolution of matter in curved spaces, you are correct on the main point - nothing is infinite in physical reality. Simply because real means measurable by definition. Infinite is not measurable and thus not real. While this is a philosophical concept, all branches of physics have confirmed this point. For example, the electron is a point particle, but the Uncertainty Principle ensures that the probability of the infinite density is zero everywhere. Similarly QED removes the electric charge singularity and so on.

@ImaginaryUnit Note however that infinity in physics is never replaced by “nearly infinite” (which is oxymoron anyway) or by “very very large”, but instead just removed completely by some new concept.

There's not an infinitely large amount of mass, there is a finite amount of mass being crammed into a zero dimensional point. The result is a point with finite mass, but infinite density.

I prefer Kip's classical explanation (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oj1AfkPQa6M https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ThuFewi-mRM), where the only "infinity" is the singularity, and it is a defect in space-time. There is no density, it is all space-time, and the mass is contained in the energy of warped space-time surrounding the singularity.

This answer is utterly and completely wrong wildly mixing Newtonian gravity with General Relativity and Euclidean concepts with the geometry of curved spaces. Except for the first line all other statements are incorrect.
